# Why double tagging attack in VLAN is unidirectional (one way)?

Tags: attacks, vulnerability, vlans

I was reading this [article](http://www.ciscopress.com/articles/article.asp?p=2181837&seqNum=10) about VLAN double tagging security issues, and started to wonder two things:

1) **Why double tagging is a one way attack?**

2) How can the adversary make a **bi-directional communication?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you read the article and understand how the attack works.

1) VLANs break up broadcast domains. So with default settings, hosts on two separate vlans such as vlan 1 and vlan 10 are not going to be able to communicate with each other unless a Layer 3 device gets involved. This is the reason the double tagging is needed, so it can HOP vlans and access a vlan it's not suppose to. When the target/victim tries to respond, they are not going to be able to "hop" back over to attackers vlan because when the victim responds it will just be a normal frame instead of a malformed frame like the attacker originally built.

Note: Trunk ports are members of all VLANs by default. Frames destined for the Native VLAN do not get retagged. This is what allowed the hidden vlan tag to get across and why the Native VLAN is a requirement of this attack. Since the target/victim is probably not going to reside on the Native VLAN, it won't be able to have this kind of communication which is what makes it uni-directional

2) With this attack, you can't. As an attacker you can malform that frame for VLAN-hopping but you can't cause the target/victim to send out malformed double-tagged frames. When the target/victim receives the frame, it is just going to look like a normal frame because the other headers were stripped by the previous switches.

Answer (score 1):

Bi-directional is possible but in a different way. This is one way communication to the target. So what you can do is send out a exploit to machines in another VLAN. Once they accept the data and get exploited, you should have them send data out a different location.

An example would be a threat actor sends a exploit double tagged to another machine in another vlan. The machine gets exploited and then runs a reverse shell out to a adversary machine on the internet. That machine can be a c&c server, there is your bi-directional communication.